# getting error in twitter streaming through flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, streaming, flume, flume-twitter

**While running the flume command i am getting the following error,i tried changing the envi variables in .bashrc along with classpath in flume.env.sh ,still no use

**`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
16/12/08 01:57:11 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
16/12/08 01:57:11 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:../conf/twitter.conf
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.path
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/datamain/tweets
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
16/12/08 01:57:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: HDFS Agent: TwitterAgent
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.channels
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.channels = MemChannel
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.fileType
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.type
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.type = hdfs
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Invalid property specified: sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval
16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Configuration property ignored: TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600

16/12/08 01:57:11 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: no context for sinkHDFS
16/12/08 01:57:12 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [TwitterAgent]
16/12/08 01:57:12 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
16/12/08 01:57:12 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel MemChannel type memory
16/12/08 01:57:12 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel MemChannel
16/12/08 01:57:12 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source Twitter, type org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
16/12/08 01:57:12 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load source type: org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource, class: org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:327)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:65)
    ... 11 more`
**Also seems like there is problem with my sink command in twitter.conf but i am unable to figure it out,below is the twitter.conf file**

```
`TwitterAgent.sources =Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels =MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = ###
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = ###
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = ###
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = ####

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords =donald trump,republican,democratic


TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type =  memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000


TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.path =hdfs://localhost:8020/datamain/tweets
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600  `
```

**here are my flume.env.sh file details**

```
    # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# If this file is placed at FLUME_CONF_DIR/flume-env.sh, it will be sourced
# during Flume startup.

# Enviroment variables can be set here.

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

# Give Flume more memory and pre-allocate, enable remote monitoring via JMX
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms500m -Xmx1000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"

# Note that the Flume conf directory is always included in the classpath.
FLUME_CLASSPATH=/home/user/hadoop_store/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**.bashrc details**

```
##Flume home directory

export FLUME_HOME=/home/user/hadoop_store/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin
export FLUME_CONF_DIR=$FLUME_HOME/conf
export FLUME_CLASSPATH=$FLUME_CONF_DIR

export PATH=$FLUME_HOME/bin:$PATH

##Flume home directory
```

**tried changing snapshot file path still didnt work,**

Comment: The error is clearly stated: `Invalid property specified`. The problem is with `TwitterAgent.sink.HDFS.hdfs`, check documentation on the proper setting string first (Googleing the problem gets me thinking that "sink" should be "sinks" but I'm not qualified in this topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking your log file messages, you are missing two things:

- Using **org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource** class in your
  configuration so `flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` must be present in
  your flume lib directory.
- Replace **sink** with **sinks** keyword below:

  `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channels = MemChannel
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path =hdfs://localhost:8020/datamain/tweets
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
  TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600`

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: thanks did that ,but now this error has generated   ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows. org.apache.flume.FlumeException: any suggestions ?

Comment: @A.T:have you placed flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in flume lib directory??